# Is it possible to alter $form_state before it is passed to user_profile_form_submit?

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

I have a form posting updates to the user account.
The problem is I need to add some more data to the post object before user_profile_form_submit gets a hold of it.

Is this possible in Drupal 7?

Comment: Why dont you try `hook_form_alter`? Also you can try with a custom validation function for that form.

Comment: I need to add the data after form has been posted but before drupal saves the data.

Comment: check `hook_validate` in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/52475/4471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There many ways to alter the $form_state values. It would be nice if we know what you wanna change so that we can say the best way to do it. Any way the following hooks can help.

- [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)
- [hook_validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_validate/7)
- hook_form_submit

  - You can have your own submit function either by overriding the `$form['#submit']` values in hook_form_alter or add one to modify the values.

Comment: I need to catch the post before drupal updates the user so I can add some extra data in with the post vars. From what I understand I can somehow add another function to call before the submit but I am not sure how to do this yet.